# Comparison of size of an entity in different images with different resolutions?

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

Can we compare the size of two objects appearing in different images with different resolutions?

Comment: Kind of difficult unless we know some kind of scales to the distances in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have some reference between the images,
either some other similar elements or the camera parameters,

If you know the different resolutions that it is easy to calculate:

relative size = resolution ratio * object_size_ratio

otherwise you must have some other spatial reference between the images.

Comment: This is what i thought. I was trying my luck because i did a fair bit of reading on this topic and found out what you said. Thanks for the help.